# assigning a string with a combination of two and separate them in a list

Tags: python

This is a simple example of what I am trying to do.
Say, I have a random list which is the following:

```
aa = 1
b = 2
c = 3
ao = 4
uw = 5
d = 6 
ih = 7
```

I give the input to the program as:

```
b d aa aw ay c
```

In the input there are strings which don't have values and are not present in the list like 'aw' and 'ay'. So, I have to change them into the strings which are present in the list. But the problem is, 'aw' and 'ay' are the combination of two strings. For example, I have to change 'aw' as ao + uw and 'ay' as ao + ih and form a list. So the new list of the input should be like,

```
b
d
aa
ao
uw
ao
ih
c
```

And the final output should be their corresponding values which is,

```
2 6 1 4 5 4 7 3
```

I could not write this in code. Could someone help please? Thank you.

Comment: How could ay be the combination of the strings ao and ih?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ...

```
str_converter = {'aa': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'ao': 4, 'uw':5, 'd':6, 'ih':7}
pre_converter = {'aw': ['ao', 'uw'], 'ay': ['ao', 'ih']}

input = ['b', 'd', 'aa', 'aw', 'ay', 'c']

work_list = []

for in_string in input:
    converted_str = pre_converter.get(in_string)
    if converted_str is None:
        work_list.append(in_string)
    else:
        work_list.extend(converted_str)

for work_string in work_list:
    print str_converter.get(work_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.  Assign the phoneme values.  You've done some of that.  You need to finish all 37.  It shouldn't be too hard.

```
aa = 1
b = 2
c = 3
ao = 4
uw = 5
d = 6 
ih = 7
```

Step 2.  Assign dipthong variables which are lists.  This isn't too hard, either.

```
aw= [ ao, uw ]
ay= [ ao, ih ]
```

Step 3.  Create a nested list.  The dipthongs will become sub-lists.

```
nested = [ b, d, aa, aw, ay, c ]
```

Step 4.  Flatten the nested list.

```
def flatten( some_list ):
    for x in some_list:
        if isinstance(x,collections.Sequence):
            for v in flatten(x):
                yield v
        else:
            yield x

result= list( flatten( nested ) )
```

Comment: This is not a homework. I just made a simple example so that I don't complicate my question. This is my research about lip synchronization in Computer Graphics. As I am beginner in python so it is a bit difficult for me proceed and also explain my question with the code I'm writing.

Comment: Are these "letters" all phonemes?

Comment: Yes, these are just the examples. But there are 37 phonemes I need to deal with. And the question I asked relates to diphthongs. As diphthongs should be broken into two separate vowels while dealing with them.

Comment: I have got step1 2 and 3 all ready before hand. I have been trying to get it running in my code.

Comment: @zingy: "I have been trying to get it running in my code."?  If you have that written, then it runs, right?  If it doesn't run, you have **specific** error messages, right?

Comment: I am sorry but I didnt understand the step 4 that you had suggested. I am trying to do what jcfollower suggested but it is not working properly. And also the error I am getting deals with the other parts of the code which is really big to post here. Thanks

Comment: @zingy: "And also the error I am getting..." either **update** the question or start a new question.  "I didnt understand the step 4"?  What **specifically** did you not understand?  Please be **specific**.  We can't guess what you're doing or what question you have.  You must actually write your question and actually copy the error message so we can see them.

Comment: I would post a new question which will be the extension of this one with the code and output.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the output is the associated number if the string is in the initial list, and if it is not, you are looking for decomposition of this string into 2 concatenated string.

First of all, you have to think of wether there is a unique decomposition or not (you might have ab+bc=ac=ad+dc for exemple).

then to solve your issue, if you are looking only for first degree decomposition (no more than 2 concatenated string), you could pre compute the concatenation in a new list.

When you have an input, you first look in the first list. If it is not in it, look at the new list of concatenated strings.

Comment: These are unique decompositions. In the actual code I am doing, there are only 4 in fact and also only first degree. I am sorry I didn't exactly get what you said in pre computing the concatenation in a new list.

Comment: pre computing would allow to limit the time of computation. Before launching your script with the input, first build a list of all possible concatenation (take all the element in the initial list and try all couple). Then, when you look for a new input, you just have to check if it is in this pre computed list.