# printing the corresponding elements of dictionary 

Tags: python

Here is the solution to the question I had asked here [assigning a string with a combination of two and separate them in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414160/assigning-a-string-with-a-combination-of-two-and-separate-them-in-a-list/7414509#7414509). The earlier question was an example and below is the actual program.

```
import sys

param_values = {
            'vowels':{
            'aa' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)],     
            'ae' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.1,0.8), (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ah' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ao' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.2,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'eh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'er' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.15,0.7),  (-1,-1)], 
            'ey' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.5),   (-1,-1)],
            'ih' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'iy' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.2,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'uh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'uw' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)],   
            'o'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.4,1.0)]       
            },
            'consonants':{
            'b'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ch' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'd'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'dh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'dx' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'f'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'g'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'hh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'jh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'k'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'l'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'm'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'n'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ng' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'p'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'r'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            's'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)],
            'sh' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            't'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'th' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'v'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'w'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'y'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)],  
            'z'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'zh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)] 
             }                         
            }

diphthong = { 
             'aw' : ['ao' , 'uw'],
             'ay' : ['ao' , 'ih'],
             'ow' : ['o' , 'aa'],
             'oy' : ['o' , 'ih']
            }   

def Usage() :
    print "Usage :python co.py phonemeFile"

def coart(phonemeFile):
    """ Function for generating parameter values looking from the global list """
    phonemeList = []
    with open("syllabifiedPhonemes.txt", "r") as pFile :
        for line in pFile :
            l = line.split()
            for phoneme in l : 
                next_phoneme = diphthong.get(phoneme)
                if next_phoneme is None :
                    phonemeList.append((phoneme, param_values.get(phoneme)))

                else : 
                    phonemeList.extend([(phoneme, param_values.get(phoneme)) for phoneme in next_phoneme])

            print "New List"
            print '\n'.join(str(l) for l in phonemeList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 : 
        Usage() 

    else :
        phonemeFile = sys.argv[1]

        coart("syllabifiedPhonemes.txt")
```

The input file syllabifiedPhonemes.txt has the following contents:

```
s aa ' m ih ' k l eh k ' t aa ' n ih t ' g eh l ' v ae ' n ih ' k aa ' p l ay k
```

The output I got is the following:

```
New List
('s', None)
('aa', None)
("'", None)
('m', None)
('ih', None)
("'", None)
('k', None)
('l', None)
('eh', None)
('k', None)
("'", None)
('t', None)
('aa', None)
("'", None)
('n', None)
('ih', None)
('t', None)
("'", None)
('g', None)
('eh', None)
('l', None)
("'", None)
('v', None)
('ae', None)
("'", None)
('n', None)
('ih', None)
("'", None)
('k', None)
('aa', None)
("'", None)
('p', None)
('l', None)
('ao', None)
('ih', None)
('k', None)
```

Now my question is, how do I display the complete dictionary with the values? I can see that I am not printing it the right way as there is the separation of vowels and consonants. How do I get the output as the following neglecting the vowels and consonants tag?

```
('s', [(-1, -1), (0.10000000000000001, 1.0), (-1, -1), (0.29999999999999999, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0), (-1, -1)])
```

P.S. For the apostrophes, None is ok as they are not in the dict.

Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the input file it's hard to tell why the code's misbehaving.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write the input file, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the section where the phonemes are added with the following:

```
if next_phoneme is None :
    phonemeList.append((phoneme, param_values.get(phoneme)))
else : 
    phonemeList.extend([(phoneme, param_values.get(phoneme)) for phoneme in next_phoneme])
```

This adds the full tuples, not just the names.

Comment: You would also want to display 'l'.

Comment: Fixed that just as you said it.

Comment: Those apostrophes are the syllable boundaries and they should display as well but there should be 'None' for them as its is not in the dict. I tried what you suggested above but it gives a syntax error.

Comment: @zingy Updated it for you, I tested it and it works now. I changed to doing it at the point GeneralBecos suggested, to avoid going over the lists multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
phonemeList.append(phoneme)
```

You need:

```
phonemeList.append((phoneme, param_values[phoneme]))
```

Your print statement will also get simplified and would just need to be:

```
print phonemeList
```

Comment: You also need to account for the dipthong case, if you do it at that point. That said, I'd agree this is probably the better time to do it.

Comment: It doesn't consider for the apostrophes.